# Creating sub menu in bash

Tags: bash, shell, submenu

I'm trying to do the following :

```
function main_menu 
{
option=0
until [ "$option" = "4" ]; do
echo "  1.) Add user"
echo "  2.) Remove user"
echo "  3.) Update user"
echo "  4.) Quit"

echo -n "Enter choice: "
read option
echo ""
case $option in
    1 ) add_user ; press_enter ;;
    2 ) remove_user ; press_enter ;;
    3 ) update_user ; press_enter ;;
    4 ) exit;;
    * ) tput setf 4;echo "Please enter 1, 2, 3, or 4";tput setf 4; 
esac
done
 }
```

In a switch case(do while option is not 4).The 3rd option will show another sub menu with switch case as follows:

```
function update_user 
{
 option=0
 until [ "$option" = "3"]; do
 echo "  1.) Update username"
 echo "  2.) Update password"
 echo "  3.) Return to menu"

 echo -n "Enter choice: "
 read option
 echo ""
 case $option in
 1 ) update_username; press_enter ;;
 2 ) update_password; press_enter ;;
 3 ) main_menu; press_enter ;;
 4 ) exit;;
 * ) tput setf 3;echo "Please enter 1, 2 or 3";tput setf 3; 
 esac
 done
  }
```

The 3rd option goes back to the main menu, but when I try to quit the sub menu keeps appearing.

Anyone can advise me on a better way?

Comment: Some code could be useful

Comment: @KonstantinV.Salikhov Updated on code

Comment: You can just use bash select builtin http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_09_06.html

Comment: @KonstantinV.Salikhov I'll try it out. Are there any other ways,though?

Comment: Start by cleaning up your code so it runs at all, and then posting. As written, your sub menu is never called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace two times `$selection` with `$option`, `break` with `exit`, remove `}` in function `update_user`, in function `update_user` add `}` after `done` and replace `"$option" = "7"` with `"$option" = "4"`.

---

```
#!/bin/bash

function update_user 
{
 option=0
 until [ "$option" = "3"]; do
 echo "  1.) Update username"
 echo "  2.) Update password"
 echo "  3.) Return to menu"

 echo -n "Enter choice: "
 read option
 echo ""
 case $option in
 1 ) update_username; press_enter ;;
 2 ) update_password; press_enter ;;
 3 ) main_menu; press_enter ;;
 4 ) break ;;
 * ) tput setf 3;echo "Please enter 1, 2 or 3";tput setf 3; 
 esac
#   }
 done
}

function main_menu 
{
option=0
until [ "$option" = "4" ]; do
echo "  1.) Add user"
echo "  2.) Remove user"
echo "  3.) Update user"
echo "  4.) Quit"

echo -n "Enter choice: "
read option
echo ""
case $option in
    1 ) add_user ; press_enter ;;
    2 ) remove_user ; press_enter ;;
    3 ) update_user ; press_enter ;;
    4 ) exit;;
    * ) tput setf 4;echo "Please enter 1, 2, 3, or 4";tput setf 4; 
esac
done
 }

main_menu
```

Comment: The code runs,but if I replace break with exit won't it exit from the program? I'm trying to return to the sub menu.

Comment: Replace only `break` with `exit` in function `main_menu`.

Comment: That's what I tried though,but nothing happens. It doesn't go back to main menu.

Comment: I've added your code as a bash script in my answer. It works for me.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by @KonstantinV.Salikhov, menus in bash are what `select` loops are for.

Here's one way you can implement your menu using `select`:

```
main_menu () {
    options=(
        "Add user"
        "Remove user"
        "Update user"
        "Quit"
    )
    select option in "${options[@]}"; do
        case $option in
            ${options[0]})
                add_user
                break
            ;;
            ${options[1]})
                remove_user
                break
            ;;
            ${options[2]})
                update_user
                break
             ;;
            ${options[3]})
                exit
             ;;
            *) 
                echo invalid option
            ;;
        esac
    done
}
main_menu
```